# Is it possible to include/require file with part of code in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to know if its possible to include part of text file as code in PHP not as text.

For example:

```
**Index.php FILE**
    <?php
    require "part1.php";
    ?>

    <div>HELLO WORKD</div>

    <?php
    require "part2.php";
    ?>


**Part1.php FILE:**

    <?php
    if(0==0) {
      Part2.php FILE:
    }
    ?>


Part2.php FILE
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: sure, it works, but the page included/required can access the index.php file var written before it's inclusion/requirment, not those after

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. require, require_once, include and include_once are your friends to enable this. Here is more info about each...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: But when I just do it using "include" I get only plain text, once the PHP code is not complete in each file! Remember that the "IF" statment is divided in two files!